# How to know correct learning rate for GradientDescentOptimizer in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I am confused on learning rate of Gradient Descent Optimizer in Tensorflow,

So suppose i am trying to predict next value from this data :

```python
x_data = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40]
y_data = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]
```

If i choose learning rate as 0.01 , Here is my program :

```python
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(777)

#x_data=[5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40]
#y_data=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]

x_data = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40]
y_data = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]

one=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
two=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))

hypo=x_data*one+two

cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypo-y_data))

train=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

ina=tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as tt:
    tt.run(ina)
    for i in range(3000):

        a,b,c,d=tt.run([train,cost,one,two])
        if i%10==0:
            print(c,d)
```

Then i am getting this output and its going in inf (that's my second confusion why its going into infinity ?)

```python
    [-20.48267746] [-1.6179111]
[ -1.06335529e+12] [ -3.75422935e+10]
[ -5.40660918e+22] [ -1.90883086e+21]
[ -2.74898110e+33] [ -9.70541703e+31]
[ nan] [ nan]
[ nan] [ nan]
[ nan] [ nan]
[ nan] [ nan]
[ nan] [ nan]
[ nan] [ nan]
[ nan] [ nan]
[ nan] [ nan]
[ nan] [ nan]
[ nan] [ nan]
[ nan] [ nan]

 ....   ....
 ....   ....
```

But if i choose `learning rate as 0.001`  then i am gettin correct output :

```python
    [-0.06046534] [-0.90016752]
[ 0.43103883] [-0.87918627]
[ 0.43091267] [-0.87557721]
[ 0.4307858] [-0.87198305]
[ 0.43065941] [-0.86840361]
[ 0.43053356] [-0.8648389]
[ 0.43040821] [-0.86128885]
[ 0.43028343] [-0.85775328]
[ 0.43015912] [-0.85423231]
[ 0.43003532] [-0.85072571]
[ 0.429912] [-0.84723359]
[ 0.42978922] [-0.84375578]
[ 0.42966694] [-0.84029222]
[ 0.42954516] [-0.83684289]
[ 0.42942387] [-0.8334077]
[ 0.42930311] [-0.82998663]
[ 0.4291828] [-0.82657957]
[ 0.42906302] [-0.82318658]
[ 0.42894369] [-0.81980747]
[ 0.4288249] [-0.81644231]
[ 0.42870659] [-0.81309086]
[ 0.42858875] [-0.80975318]
[ 0.42847139] [-0.80642921]
[ 0.42835453] [-0.80311882]
[ 0.42823812] [-0.79982209]
[ 0.42812222] [-0.79653889]
[ 0.42800677] [-0.7932691]
[ 0.42789182] [-0.79001278]
[ 0.42777732] [-0.78676981]
[ 0.42766327] [-0.78354019]
[ 0.42754975] [-0.78032386]
[ 0.42743665] [-0.77712065]
[ 0.42732403] [-0.77393067]
[ 0.42721185] [-0.77075368]
[ 0.42710015] [-0.76758981]
[ 0.4269889] [-0.76443887]
[ 0.42687812] [-0.76130092]
[ 0.42676777] [-0.75817585]
[ 0.42665792] [-0.75506359]
[ 0.42654848] [-0.75196409]
[ 0.42643949] [-0.74887735]
[ 0.42633098] [-0.74580324]
[ 0.42622289] [-0.74274176]
[ 0.42611524] [-0.73969287]
[ 0.42600802] [-0.73665649]
[ 0.42590126] [-0.73363262]
[ 0.42579496] [-0.73062116]
[ 0.42568904] [-0.72762191]
[ 0.42558363] [-0.72463512]
[ 0.42547861] [-0.72166055]
[ 0.425374] [-0.7186982]
[ 0.42526984] [-0.71574789]
[ 0.4251661] [-0.71280998]
[ 0.42506284] [-0.70988399]
[ 0.42495993] [-0.70696992]
[ 0.42485747] [-0.70406777]
[ 0.42475539] [-0.70117754]
[ 0.42465383] [-0.69829923]
[ 0.42455259] [-0.69543284]
[ 0.42445183] [-0.69257832]
[ 0.42435145] [-0.68973517]
[ 0.4242515] [-0.68690395]
[ 0.42415196] [-0.68408424]
[ 0.4240528] [-0.6812762]
[ 0.42395407] [-0.67847955]
[ 0.42385572] [-0.67569441]
[ 0.42375779] [-0.6729207]
[ 0.42366028] [-0.67015845]
[ 0.42356315] [-0.66740751]
[ 0.42346644] [-0.66466784]
[ 0.42337012] [-0.66193944]
[ 0.42327416] [-0.65922225]
[ 0.42317864] [-0.65651619]
[ 0.42308348] [-0.65382123]
[ 0.42298874] [-0.65113741]
[ 0.42289436] [-0.6484645]
[ 0.42280039] [-0.64580262]
[ 0.42270681] [-0.6431517]
[ 0.42261356] [-0.64051157]
[ 0.42252076] [-0.63788235]
[ 0.42242831] [-0.63526386]
[ 0.42233622] [-0.6326561]
[ 0.42224455] [-0.63005906]
[ 0.42215326] [-0.62747276]
[ 0.42206231] [-0.62489706]
[ 0.42197174] [-0.62233192]
[ 0.42188156] [-0.61977726]
[ 0.42179173] [-0.61723322]
[ 0.42170227] [-0.61469954]
[ 0.42161322] [-0.6121763]
[ 0.42152449] [-0.60966337]
[ 0.4214361] [-0.60716075]
[ 0.42134812] [-0.60466844]
[ 0.42126048] [-0.60218632]
[ 0.42117321] [-0.5997144]
[ 0.42108631] [-0.59725261]
[ 0.42099974] [-0.59480095]
[ 0.42091355] [-0.5923593]
[ 0.42082772] [-0.58992773]
[ 0.42074221] [-0.58750612]
[ 0.42065707] [-0.58509439]
[ 0.42057225] [-0.58269262]
[ 0.42048782] [-0.58030075]
[ 0.42040369] [-0.57791865]
[ 0.42031991] [-0.57554632]
[ 0.42023653] [-0.57318377]
[ 0.42015347] [-0.57083094]
[ 0.42007077] [-0.5684877]
[ 0.41998836] [-0.56615406]
[ 0.41990632] [-0.56383008]
[ 0.41982457] [-0.56151563]
[ 0.41974318] [-0.55921066]
[ 0.41966218] [-0.55691516]
[ 0.41958147] [-0.55462909]
[ 0.4195011] [-0.55235237]
[ 0.41942102] [-0.55008501]
[ 0.41934133] [-0.54782701]
[ 0.41926193] [-0.54557824]
[ 0.41918284] [-0.54333872]
[ 0.4191041] [-0.54110831]
[ 0.41902569] [-0.53888714]
[ 0.41894755] [-0.5366751]
[ 0.41886982] [-0.53447211]
[ 0.41879237] [-0.53227806]
[ 0.41871524] [-0.53009313]
[ 0.41863838] [-0.52791727]
[ 0.41856188] [-0.52575034]
[ 0.41848567] [-0.52359205]
[ 0.41840979] [-0.52144271]
[ 0.41833425] [-0.51930231]
[ 0.41825897] [-0.51717055]
[ 0.41818401] [-0.51504761]
[ 0.41810936] [-0.51293337]
[ 0.41803503] [-0.51082784]
[ 0.417961] [-0.50873089]
[ 0.41788727] [-0.50664258]
[ 0.41781384] [-0.50456285]
[ 0.4177407] [-0.50249171]
[ 0.4176679] [-0.50042903]
[ 0.41759539] [-0.49837482]
[ 0.41752315] [-0.49632904]
[ 0.41745123] [-0.49429163]
[ 0.41737959] [-0.4922626]
[ 0.41730824] [-0.49024191]
[ 0.41723716] [-0.48822951]
[ 0.41716644] [-0.4862254]
[ 0.41709596] [-0.48422945]
[ 0.41702577] [-0.48224172]
[ 0.41695589] [-0.48026216]
[ 0.4168863] [-0.47829071]
[ 0.41681695] [-0.47632736]
[ 0.41674796] [-0.47437206]
[ 0.41667923] [-0.47242478]
[ 0.41661072] [-0.47048554]
[ 0.41654253] [-0.46855426]
[ 0.41647464] [-0.46663091]
[ 0.41640702] [-0.46471542]
[ 0.41633967] [-0.4628078]
[ 0.41627261] [-0.46090803]
[ 0.41620579] [-0.45901603]
[ 0.41613927] [-0.4571318]
[ 0.41607302] [-0.4552553]
[ 0.41600704] [-0.45338652]
[ 0.41594133] [-0.45152542]
[ 0.41587588] [-0.44967195]
[ 0.41581073] [-0.44782609]
[ 0.41574579] [-0.44598779]
[ 0.41568118] [-0.44415703]
[ 0.41561681] [-0.44233382]
[ 0.41555271] [-0.44051811]
[ 0.41548887] [-0.43870986]
[ 0.4154253] [-0.43690899]
[ 0.41536197] [-0.43511549]
[ 0.41529894] [-0.43332937]
[ 0.41523612] [-0.43155059]
[ 0.41517356] [-0.42977911]
[ 0.41511127] [-0.4280149]
[ 0.41504925] [-0.42625797]
[ 0.41498747] [-0.42450821]
[ 0.41492593] [-0.42276564]
[ 0.41486469] [-0.42103022]
[ 0.41480365] [-0.41930193]
[ 0.41474292] [-0.41758072]
[ 0.41468239] [-0.41586661]
[ 0.4146221] [-0.41415951]
[ 0.41456211] [-0.41245943]
[ 0.41450229] [-0.4107663]
[ 0.41444278] [-0.40908015]
[ 0.4143835] [-0.40740094]
[ 0.41432443] [-0.40572858]
[ 0.41426563] [-0.40406311]
[ 0.4142071] [-0.40240449]
[ 0.41414878] [-0.40075263]
[ 0.41409069] [-0.39910758]
[ 0.41403285] [-0.39746928]
[ 0.41397524] [-0.39583766]
[ 0.41391787] [-0.39421278]
[ 0.41386077] [-0.39259458]
[ 0.41380385] [-0.39098299]
[ 0.41374719] [-0.38937804]
[ 0.41369078] [-0.38777968]
[ 0.41363457] [-0.38618785]
[ 0.41357857] [-0.38460258]
[ 0.41352287] [-0.38302383]
[ 0.41346738] [-0.38145158]
[ 0.41341206] [-0.37988576]
[ 0.41335702] [-0.37832636]
[ 0.41330215] [-0.37677333]
[ 0.41324756] [-0.37522671]
[ 0.41319317] [-0.37368643]
[ 0.41313902] [-0.37215248]
[ 0.41308507] [-0.37062484]
[ 0.41303137] [-0.36910346]
[ 0.4129779] [-0.36758831]
[ 0.41292462] [-0.36607942]
[ 0.41287157] [-0.36457673]
[ 0.41281876] [-0.36308014]
[ 0.41276613] [-0.36158973]
[ 0.41271371] [-0.36010543]
[ 0.41266152] [-0.35862723]
[ 0.41260952] [-0.357155]
[ 0.41255775] [-0.35568899]
[ 0.41250622] [-0.35422897]
[ 0.41245487] [-0.35277492]
[ 0.41240376] [-0.35132682]
[ 0.41235286] [-0.34988469]
[ 0.41230217] [-0.34844851]
[ 0.41225165] [-0.34701818]
[ 0.41220134] [-0.34559363]
[ 0.41215128] [-0.34417504]
[ 0.41210139] [-0.34276217]
[ 0.41205171] [-0.3413552]
[ 0.41200227] [-0.33995393]
[ 0.41195297] [-0.33855847]
[ 0.41190392] [-0.33716872]
[ 0.41185504] [-0.33578467]
[ 0.41180637] [-0.33440632]
[ 0.41175792] [-0.33303359]
[ 0.41170964] [-0.3316665]
[ 0.4116616] [-0.33030504]
[ 0.4116137] [-0.32894915]
[ 0.41156605] [-0.32759884]
[ 0.41151857] [-0.32625404]
[ 0.41147125] [-0.32491481]
[ 0.41142419] [-0.32358104]
[ 0.41137731] [-0.32225275]
[ 0.41133058] [-0.32092994]
[ 0.41128409] [-0.31961253]
[ 0.41123778] [-0.31830055]
[ 0.41119161] [-0.31699392]
[ 0.41114569] [-0.31569266]
[ 0.41109994] [-0.31439677]
[ 0.41105434] [-0.31310621]
[ 0.41100898] [-0.31182092]
[ 0.4109638] [-0.31054091]
[ 0.41091877] [-0.30926618]
[ 0.41087398] [-0.30799666]
[ 0.41082937] [-0.30673239]
[ 0.4107849] [-0.30547327]
[ 0.41074061] [-0.30421934]
[ 0.41069651] [-0.30297056]
[ 0.41065264] [-0.30172691]
[ 0.41060886] [-0.30048832]
[ 0.41056535] [-0.29925483]
[ 0.41052195] [-0.29802641]
[ 0.4104788] [-0.29680306]
[ 0.41043577] [-0.29558468]
[ 0.41039294] [-0.29437134]
[ 0.41035026] [-0.293163]
[ 0.41030779] [-0.29195961]
[ 0.41026548] [-0.29076111]
[ 0.41022334] [-0.28956759]
[ 0.41018137] [-0.28837892]
[ 0.41013956] [-0.28719518]
[ 0.41009796] [-0.28601629]
[ 0.41005653] [-0.28484219]
[ 0.41001526] [-0.28367293]
[ 0.40997413] [-0.28250849]
[ 0.40993318] [-0.28134882]
[ 0.40989238] [-0.28019392]
[ 0.40985179] [-0.27904376]
[ 0.40981135] [-0.27789828]
[ 0.40977108] [-0.27675754]
[ 0.40973094] [-0.27562147]
[ 0.40969101] [-0.27449009]
[ 0.40965122] [-0.27336332]
[ 0.40961161] [-0.2722412]
[ 0.40957215] [-0.27112368]
[ 0.40953287] [-0.27001071]
[ 0.40949374] [-0.26890236]
[ 0.40945476] [-0.26779851]
[ 0.40941596] [-0.26669925]
[ 0.40937731] [-0.26560447]
[ 0.4093388] [-0.26451415]
[ 0.40930048] [-0.2634283]
[ 0.4092623] [-0.26234692]
[ 0.40922427] [-0.26127002]
[ 0.40918639] [-0.26019755]
[ 0.40914869] [-0.25912943]
[ 0.40911114] [-0.25806573]
```

Again if i choose  learning rate 0.0001 then i am not getting correct output:

```python
[ 1.98175597] [-0.82839316]
[ 0.82685816] [-0.86880374]
[ 0.53213042] [-0.87884581]
[ 0.45690936] [-0.88113832]
[ 0.43770415] [-0.88145328]
[ 0.43279362] [-0.88126367]
[ 0.43153098] [-0.88094544]
[ 0.43119925] [-0.88059455]
[ 0.43110508] [-0.88023537]
[ 0.43107152] [-0.87987429]
[ 0.43105346] [-0.87951249]
[ 0.43103933] [-0.87915069]
[ 0.43102625] [-0.87878931]
[ 0.43101344] [-0.8784281]
[ 0.43100062] [-0.8780669]
[ 0.43098781] [-0.87770569]
[ 0.43097505] [-0.87734485]
[ 0.43096232] [-0.87698424]
[ 0.4309496] [-0.87662363]
[ 0.43093687] [-0.87626302]
[ 0.43092415] [-0.87590277]
[ 0.43091145] [-0.87554276]
[ 0.43089876] [-0.87518275]
[ 0.43088603] [-0.87482274]
[ 0.43087333] [-0.87446308]
[ 0.43086067] [-0.87410367]
[ 0.43084797] [-0.87374425]
[ 0.43083528] [-0.87338483]
[ 0.43082261] [-0.87302572]
[ 0.43080994] [-0.8726669]
[ 0.43079728] [-0.87230808]
[ 0.43078461] [-0.87194926]
[ 0.43077198] [-0.87159073]
[ 0.43075931] [-0.87123251]
[ 0.43074667] [-0.87087429]
[ 0.43073404] [-0.87051606]
[ 0.43072137] [-0.87015808]
[ 0.43070877] [-0.86980045]
[ 0.43069616] [-0.86944282]
[ 0.43068352] [-0.86908519]
[ 0.43067092] [-0.8687278]
[ 0.43065831] [-0.86837077]
[ 0.4306457] [-0.86801374]
[ 0.4306331] [-0.86765671]
[ 0.43062052] [-0.86729985]
[ 0.43060791] [-0.86694342]
[ 0.43059534] [-0.86658698]
[ 0.43058276] [-0.86623055]
[ 0.43057019] [-0.86587429]
[ 0.43055761] [-0.86551845]
[ 0.43054506] [-0.86516261]
[ 0.43053252] [-0.86480677]
[ 0.43051994] [-0.86445105]
[ 0.43050742] [-0.86409581]
[ 0.43049487] [-0.86374056]
[ 0.43048233] [-0.86338532]
[ 0.43046981] [-0.86303014]
[ 0.43045726] [-0.86267549]
[ 0.43044475] [-0.86232084]
[ 0.43043223] [-0.86196619]
[ 0.43041971] [-0.86161155]
[ 0.4304072] [-0.86125749]
[ 0.43039468] [-0.86090344]
[ 0.43038216] [-0.86054939]
[ 0.43036965] [-0.86019534]
[ 0.43035713] [-0.85984182]
[ 0.43034461] [-0.85948837]
[ 0.43033212] [-0.85913491]
[ 0.43031967] [-0.85878146]
[ 0.43030721] [-0.85842848]
[ 0.43029472] [-0.85807562]
[ 0.43028226] [-0.85772276]
[ 0.43026984] [-0.8573699]
[ 0.43025738] [-0.85701746]
[ 0.43024495] [-0.85666519]
[ 0.43023252] [-0.85631293]
[ 0.4302201] [-0.85596067]
[ 0.43020767] [-0.85560876]
[ 0.43019524] [-0.85525709]
[ 0.43018284] [-0.85490543]
[ 0.43017042] [-0.85455376]
[ 0.43015802] [-0.85420239]
[ 0.43014562] [-0.85385132]
[ 0.43013322] [-0.85350025]
[ 0.43012086] [-0.85314918]
[ 0.43010846] [-0.85279834]
[ 0.43009609] [-0.85244787]
[ 0.43008372] [-0.85209739]
[ 0.43007135] [-0.85174692]
[ 0.43005899] [-0.85139656]
[ 0.43004665] [-0.85104668]
[ 0.43003428] [-0.8506968]
[ 0.43002194] [-0.85034692]
[ 0.43000957] [-0.8499971]
[ 0.42999727] [-0.84964782]
[ 0.42998493] [-0.84929854]
[ 0.42997259] [-0.84894925]
[ 0.42996028] [-0.84859997]
[ 0.42994797] [-0.84825122]
[ 0.42993566] [-0.84790254]
[ 0.42992336] [-0.84755385]
[ 0.42991105] [-0.84720516]
[ 0.42989877] [-0.84685695]
[ 0.42988646] [-0.84650886]
[ 0.42987418] [-0.84616077]
[ 0.4298619] [-0.84581268]
[ 0.42984962] [-0.84546494]
[ 0.42983735] [-0.84511745]
[ 0.4298251] [-0.84476995]
[ 0.42981282] [-0.84442246]
[ 0.42980057] [-0.84407526]
[ 0.42978832] [-0.84372836]
[ 0.42977607] [-0.84338146]
[ 0.42976385] [-0.84303457]
[ 0.4297516] [-0.84268785]
[ 0.42973939] [-0.84234154]
[ 0.42972714] [-0.84199524]
[ 0.42971492] [-0.84164894]
[ 0.4297027] [-0.84130269]
[ 0.42969048] [-0.84095699]
[ 0.42967826] [-0.84061128]
[ 0.42966604] [-0.84026557]
[ 0.42965382] [-0.83991987]
[ 0.4296416] [-0.83957469]
[ 0.42962939] [-0.83922958]
[ 0.42961717] [-0.83888447]
[ 0.42960498] [-0.83853936]
[ 0.42959282] [-0.83819467]
[ 0.42958066] [-0.83785015]
[ 0.4295685] [-0.83750564]
[ 0.42955634] [-0.83716112]
[ 0.42954418] [-0.83681691]
[ 0.42953205] [-0.83647299]
[ 0.42951992] [-0.83612907]
[ 0.42950779] [-0.83578515]
[ 0.42949563] [-0.83544135]
[ 0.42948353] [-0.83509803]
[ 0.4294714] [-0.83475471]
[ 0.4294593] [-0.83441138]
[ 0.42944717] [-0.83406806]
[ 0.42943507] [-0.83372533]
[ 0.42942297] [-0.83338261]
[ 0.4294109] [-0.83303988]
[ 0.42939878] [-0.83269715]
[ 0.42938671] [-0.8323549]
[ 0.42937461] [-0.83201277]
[ 0.42936257] [-0.83167064]
[ 0.42935047] [-0.83132851]
[ 0.42933843] [-0.83098674]
[ 0.42932636] [-0.8306452]
[ 0.42931429] [-0.83030367]
[ 0.42930225] [-0.82996213]
[ 0.42929021] [-0.82962078]
[ 0.42927817] [-0.82927984]
[ 0.42926612] [-0.8289389]
[ 0.42925411] [-0.82859796]
[ 0.42924204] [-0.82825708]
[ 0.42923003] [-0.82791674]
[ 0.42921802] [-0.8275764]
[ 0.42920604] [-0.82723606]
[ 0.42919403] [-0.82689571]
[ 0.42918202] [-0.82655585]
[ 0.42917004] [-0.8262161]
[ 0.42915803] [-0.82587636]
[ 0.42914605] [-0.82553661]
[ 0.42913407] [-0.82519722]
[ 0.42912209] [-0.82485807]
[ 0.42911011] [-0.82451892]
[ 0.42909813] [-0.82417977]
[ 0.42908618] [-0.8238408]
[ 0.42907423] [-0.82350224]
[ 0.42906228] [-0.82316369]
[ 0.42905033] [-0.82282513]
[ 0.42903838] [-0.82248658]
[ 0.42902645] [-0.82214862]
[ 0.42901453] [-0.82181066]
[ 0.42900261] [-0.8214727]
[ 0.42899066] [-0.82113475]
[ 0.42897874] [-0.8207972]
[ 0.42896682] [-0.82045984]
[ 0.4289549] [-0.82012248]
[ 0.42894298] [-0.81978512]
[ 0.42893106] [-0.81944799]
[ 0.42891914] [-0.81911123]
[ 0.42890722] [-0.81877446]
[ 0.42889529] [-0.8184377]
[ 0.4288834] [-0.81810099]
[ 0.42887154] [-0.81776482]
[ 0.42885965] [-0.81742865]
[ 0.42884779] [-0.81709248]
[ 0.42883593] [-0.81675631]
[ 0.4288241] [-0.81642061]
[ 0.42881224] [-0.81608504]
[ 0.4288004] [-0.81574947]
[ 0.42878857] [-0.81541389]
[ 0.42877674] [-0.81507862]
[ 0.42876491] [-0.81474364]
[ 0.42875308] [-0.81440866]
[ 0.42874125] [-0.81407368]
[ 0.42872944] [-0.81373882]
[ 0.42871761] [-0.81340444]
[ 0.42870581] [-0.81307006]
[ 0.42869401] [-0.81273568]
[ 0.42868224] [-0.81240129]
[ 0.42867044] [-0.81206739]
[ 0.42865866] [-0.8117336]
[ 0.42864686] [-0.81139982]
[ 0.42863509] [-0.81106603]
[ 0.42862332] [-0.81073254]
[ 0.42861155] [-0.81039935]
[ 0.4285998] [-0.81006616]
[ 0.42858803] [-0.80973297]
[ 0.42857626] [-0.80939984]
[ 0.42856455] [-0.80906725]
[ 0.42855281] [-0.80873466]
[ 0.42854106] [-0.80840206]
[ 0.42852932] [-0.80806947]
[ 0.42851761] [-0.80773735]
[ 0.4285059] [-0.80740535]
[ 0.42849416] [-0.80707335]
[ 0.42848244] [-0.80674136]
[ 0.42847073] [-0.8064096]
[ 0.42845905] [-0.8060782]
[ 0.42844734] [-0.80574679]
[ 0.42843565] [-0.80541539]
[ 0.42842394] [-0.80508399]
[ 0.42841226] [-0.80475318]
[ 0.42840061] [-0.80442238]
[ 0.42838892] [-0.80409157]
[ 0.42837724] [-0.80376077]
[ 0.42836559] [-0.80343038]
[ 0.42835391] [-0.80310017]
[ 0.42834228] [-0.80276996]
[ 0.4283306] [-0.80243975]
[ 0.42831898] [-0.80210972]
[ 0.42830732] [-0.8017801]
[ 0.4282957] [-0.80145049]
[ 0.42828405] [-0.80112088]
[ 0.42827243] [-0.80079126]
[ 0.4282608] [-0.80046219]
[ 0.42824918] [-0.80013317]
[ 0.42823756] [-0.79980415]
[ 0.42822593] [-0.79947513]
[ 0.42821431] [-0.79914641]
[ 0.42820269] [-0.79881799]
[ 0.42819107] [-0.79848957]
[ 0.42817944] [-0.79816115]
[ 0.42816782] [-0.79783273]
[ 0.42815623] [-0.7975049]
[ 0.42814466] [-0.79717708]
[ 0.4281331] [-0.79684925]
[ 0.42812154] [-0.79652143]
[ 0.42810997] [-0.79619396]
[ 0.42809841] [-0.79586673]
[ 0.42808688] [-0.7955395]
[ 0.42807531] [-0.79521227]
[ 0.42806378] [-0.79488516]
[ 0.42805225] [-0.79455853]
[ 0.42804071] [-0.79423189]
[ 0.42802918] [-0.79390526]
[ 0.42801768] [-0.79357862]
[ 0.42800614] [-0.79325241]
[ 0.42799467] [-0.79292637]
[ 0.42798313] [-0.79260033]
[ 0.42797163] [-0.7922743]
[ 0.42796013] [-0.79194844]
[ 0.42794862] [-0.791623]
[ 0.42793715] [-0.79129755]
[ 0.42792565] [-0.79097211]
[ 0.42791417] [-0.79064667]
[ 0.4279027] [-0.79032171]
[ 0.42789125] [-0.78999686]
[ 0.42787978] [-0.78967202]
[ 0.42786831] [-0.78934717]
[ 0.42785686] [-0.78902256]
[ 0.42784542] [-0.78869832]
[ 0.42783397] [-0.78837407]
[ 0.42782253] [-0.78804982]
[ 0.42781109] [-0.78772557]
[ 0.42779964] [-0.78740185]
[ 0.42778823] [-0.7870782]
[ 0.42777681] [-0.78675455]
[ 0.42776537] [-0.7864309]
[ 0.42775396] [-0.78610754]
[ 0.42774257] [-0.78578448]
[ 0.42773116] [-0.78546143]
[ 0.42771974] [-0.78513837]
[ 0.42770836] [-0.78481531]
[ 0.42769697] [-0.78449285]
[ 0.42768559] [-0.78417039]
[ 0.42767423] [-0.78384793]
[ 0.42766282] [-0.78352547]
[ 0.42765146] [-0.7832033]
[ 0.42764008] [-0.78288144]
[ 0.42762873] [-0.78255957]
[ 0.42761737] [-0.78223771]
[ 0.42760602] [-0.78191584]
[ 0.42759466] [-0.78159457]
[ 0.42758334] [-0.78127331]
[ 0.42757198] [-0.78095204]
```

So my question is , How i am going to know which learning rate is best for my equation and for my prediction ? How i am going to choose right learning rate ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you researched what `GradientDescent` and `learning rate` is?

Comment: @layog yup i know little bit theory of partial derivation in GradientDescent.

Comment: if you've read `GradientDescent`, then you'll know that the way we update the parameters of our network is based on a hyper-parameter called `learning rate`

Comment: by parameter you mean "minimizing the cost function" and by "hyper-parameter" you mean "how slowly or fastly" we are minimizing the cost function ?

Comment: Yes, one of the hyper parameter `learning rate` governs how fast or slow we are minimizing the cost function. But by parameter i mean your `one` and `two`

Answer (score 3):

Actually is funny since I am writing a book on deep learning and the last chapter I wrote deals with this exact problem. What you are observing are three cases:

1) Learning rate too big: what happens is that the steps taken when updating the weights (-lambda * gradient of cost function) are too big and therefore instead of getting close to the minimum of the cost function they get far away, and therefore at a certain point the numbers gets so big that Python gives you nan.

2) with a smaller learning rate everything seems to work fine. You move nicely toward the minimum

3) with an even smaller learning rate it will simply take forever to get to a minimum. As you see from your numbers the cost function is going down, but very very slowly.

There is not really a way of knowing what the right learning rate is. Here some tips

1) Normalize your inputs so that they are not too big (you could divide them by their sum for example)
2) plot the cost function vs. the iteration and try different learning rates. You should see the cost function decreasing and the reaching a plateau. Then you know you are in the right direction.

There are more sophisiticated algorithm that implies changint the learning rate during the process, but I would stick to what you are trying at the beginning.

But really, plotting the cost function vs iterations (or epochs) gives you a nice tool for checking if the learning rate is good or not.

Hope that helps, Umberto

Answer (score 0):

So you should know a bit about learning rate in detail. So when you perform gradient descent, you want to get to local minima with each step of the gradient. So learning rate lets you decide how big a step you would take towards the minima where the cost is least.

If your learning rate is large, you would take large step towards the minima, however you can overshoot and end up going ahead of the minima, which in turn would not help in finding the minima.

If learning rate is small, you would take a lot of time in reaching the minima and that wont be effective either.

In real practice, I choose from a variety of learning rate to check which one performs better computationally.